# How do I use the AsQueryable method asynchronously with MongoDb C# Driver 2.1?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

The release of version 2.1 of the MongoDb C# Driver has recently reintroduced the method `AsQueryable`, but I am struggling to find a way of calling it asynchronously.

With Entity Framework this would be achieved using `QueryableExtensions.ToListAsync` but I can't see an equivalent using MongoDb.

So given a repository method such as:

```
public IQueryable<MyType> GetFiltered(Expression<Func<MyType, bool>> predicate)
{
        return Database.GetCollection<MyType>(typeof(MyType).Name).AsQueryable().Where(predicate);
}
```

I wanted to do something like

```
var myTypes = await MyRepository.GetFiltered(t => t.Id == 1).ToListAsync();
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You're returning the wrong type from the `GetFiltered` function. It should be returning an `IMongoQueryable<MyType>` instead of `IQueryable<MyType>`:

```
public IMongoQueryable<MyType> GetFiltered(Expression<Func<MyType, bool>> predicate)
{
    return Database.GetCollection<MyType>(typeof(MyType).Name).AsQueryable()
        .Where(predicate);
}
```

You can then successfully call it as:

```
var myTypes = await MyRepository.GetFiltered(t => t.Id == 1).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 16):

I am posting this later as an update for the newer versions of MongoDB driver.

In the newer versions of MongoDB, you can call it asynchronously.
You need to include the MongoDB.Driver.Linq:

```
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
var myTypes = await Database.GetCollection<MyType>().AsQueryable()
.Where(t => t.Id == 1).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 6):

I up-voted the accepted answer.

If you need to abstract away the `IMongoQueryable` interface from the caller this little extension helper may be useful.

```
public static class MongoQueryableMixIn
{
    public static Task<List<T>> ToMongoListAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> mongoQueryOnly)
    {
        return ((IMongoQueryable<T>) mongoQueryOnly).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Kinda surprised this isn't built-in.

Comment: I just realized I wasn't using async methods with `AsQueryable` with MongoDB because .Where returns IQueryable. Entity framework provides `EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions` class with stuff like that.

Comment: I just found there is `Find` method that returns IFindFluent and you can use it instead of AsQueryable+Where

Answer (score 1):

At first you must call `ToCursorAsync()` for `IMonqoQuarable<T>` object, and then call `ToListAsync()` for the awaited IAsyncCursor result:

```
public IMongoQueryable<MyType> GetFiltered(Expression<Func<MyType, bool>> predicate)
{
    return Database.GetCollection<MyType>(typeof(MyType).Name).AsQueryable()
        .Where(predicate);
}
```

And then

```
var myTypes = await(await MyRepository.GetFiltered(t => t.Id == 1).ToCursorAsync()).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

As JohnnyHK mentioned in the accepted answer, the return type is incorrect and should be `IMongoQueryable<T>`, however, this is not all that is required.

To do the .ToListAsync() on a `IMongoQueryable<T>` object, you also need to include the namespace `using MongoDB.Driver.Linq`. Now this is a no-brainer if your `IMongoQueryable<T>` interface provider is in the same file as where you want to call the .ToListAsync(), but in my case, a base class supplies the `IMongoQueryable<T>` interface, and I want to use it in my derived class.

I needed to add the `using MongoDB.Driver.Linq` to get access to that extension method.